# how to sum two result using php $_post

Tags: php, post, sum

i want to sum of result 1 and result 2 
how can i do it please help me to fix this issue

thanks

---

example:
$res + res1
=final result

this is result 1 code

```
<?php //Starting of php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))//if the submit button has pressed
    {
    $first = $_POST['first']; //Getting Value of first integer from add.html
    $sec = $_POST['sec']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $res = $first * $sec *75 /365 /30; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable
    echo 'Added Result:';

    echo number_format((round($res, 1)),3);


    }
    //Ending of php
    ?>
```

and this is 2nd result code

```
<?php //Starting of php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//if the submit button has pressed
{
$days1 = $_POST['days1']; //Getting Value of first integer from add.html
$year1 = $_POST['year1']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
$res1 = $days1 * $year1 *75 /365 /30; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable
echo 'Added Result:';

echo number_format((round($res1, 1)),3);


}
//Ending of php
?>
```

Comment: You are saying *sum* and what you are doing is *$first * $sec *75 /365 /30* so question is unclear

Comment: Are these on the same page or different files?

Comment: Why is multiplication described as 'adding'?

Comment: So what's wrong with the answer from the [**first question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945587/how-to-round-figure-value-using-php-post) you asked and accepted 20 mins. ago?

Comment: dear @Fred-ii- this is different questn thats why i ask

Comment: $first and $sec both are value of submit form

Comment: So you're wanting to get results from 2 different pages then. @msalman

Comment: if user type $first amount and $sec amount then it will calculate separate and after that it will calculate overall total understand  @Mr.Alien

Comment: no this is single page and one from but it is calculate sum separate and after that together over all sum

Comment: The answer below didn't work? @msalman it's basically `$result = $res + $res2; echo $result;`

Comment: we can make on to both of them result and get final result as you want sum of both, as mention below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php //Starting of php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))//if the submit button has pressed
    {
    $first = $_POST['first']; //Getting Value of first integer from add.html
    $sec = $_POST['sec']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $days1 = $_POST['days1']; //Getting Value of first integer from add.html
    $year1 = $_POST['year1']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $res1 = $days1 * $year1 *75 /365 /30; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable    
    $res = $first * $sec *75 /365 /30; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable
    $result1  = number_format((round($res1, 1)),3);
        echo 'Added Result:';

    $result2 = number_format((round($res, 1)),3);
    echo $final_result   = number_format(($result1 +$result2),3);

    }
    //Ending of php
    ?>
```

Comment: zeeshan can u give me your email id of fb?

Comment: you can see on my profile, if this answer help you please accept.